# Hive External Tables keeping old data file after Insert Overwrite operation in HDP 3.1

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdp

I am executing the Insert overwrite operations in Hive (HDP 3.1). The problem is that it keeps adding base and delta files where base files contain the newly inserted data and delta contains the old data before overwrite operations.

Querying on Hive provides me the newly added data only, but when it comes to spark - It tends to output both the old and new data from delta and base files which resides on HDFS location.

I need to find solution for below -

1) Is there any way which does not allow Hive to store delta files in first place while using insert overwrite operations - (Any setting?)

2) Why is spark fetching the old data? Does it always refer to the table locations internally? How can i stop it from reading the delta files?

Note: Our admin has configured Hive Warehouse connector to read from any database in Hive as described in HDP documentation. And I dont want to manually delete the the files using **hadoop fs -rm -r file** before reading data into spark. Could anyone please provide any pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: overwrite doesn't work in case of external table since it involves removing the previous data altogether which is inconsistent with the external table's "remove meta but keep data" property. there's nothing wrong with directly calling hadoop rm to get rid of prev.data, but you have to do that before insertion and you should invoke "msck repair table <tablename>" right after it

Comment: @Akshay please share the query you are trying i may help you